# Build ArcGIS Model to Select by Location (Within a Distance) and Export to KML with an Iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, kml, iterator, select-by-location

I have a parcel shapefile and point data. I need to select parcels within 0.5 miles of each point and export that data to KML then repeat the set of each point (Iteration).

The KML also needs to be saved as an ID field each point has. I have tried to do this with Model Builder. How would you go about accomplishing this task? I dont know python at the moment but could learn if it is easiest to accomplish this task that way.

This is what I have so far with Model builder:

[image]

Comment: This can be easily achieved with modelbuilder, you need to show us what you have done so far?

Comment: The On Hold reason may seem better suited to Python etc coding, but here the "code snippet" we want you to show so we can help (rather than do for you) is the part of your model where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include what I had done so far on model builder. I have attached the image to my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this combination:

Iterate Feature Selections > Select By Location (Relationship = Within A Distance) > Layer To KML

[image]

To include points object id in KML file name, there is a trick. Simply fill **Layer to KML** output path like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ArcGIS\Point_%Value%.kmz
```

[image]

The value will populate by the objectid of the current point feature.

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn't putting the iteration first and that was causing my issue.